# как запустить flutter проект на ios?

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, dart

Могу ли я запускать свой flutter проект на реальном ios устройстве? Как это нужно делать и обязателен ли xcode для этого?

Comment: Да, вам обязательно нужно иметь MacOS и XCode. Запускается также как и на android (дебаг версия): flutter run

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#ios-setup

Comment: @MiT , а возможно ли подключить андроид к мак ос? Если да, то как это работает?

Comment: Да, возможно, с этим проблем вообще нет. [Достаточно установить android-platform-tools, любым удобным для вас способом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314718/8387227). Работает примерно также как и на других ОС.

Comment: Но для сборки Flutter под android, вам в любом случае придется устоновить ряд других вспомогательных SDK. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#install-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Для полноценной и удобной разработки на flutter под IOS, да вам необходимо иметь macOs и xcode, **но** можете воспользоваться сервисами [flutlab](https://flutlab.io/) или [code magic](https://codemagic.io/), для того чтобы собрать приложение под IOS.

[Гайд по flutLab](https://dev.to/real_rijin/developing-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-2g1m)

[Гайд по codeMagic](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)