# Как протестировать приложение на IOS?

Tags: android, android-studio, ios, flutter, dart

Всем привет, написал приложение используя flutter, по идее, оно должно подойти под обе ОС, но я хотел бы убедиться, у меня нет техники apple кроме iphone. Сижу сам на убунту.
1)Суть вопроса, могу ли я добавить айфон в андроид эмулятор (андроид студия)? Если да, то как?

2)Могу ли я к компу подключить айфон и протестить на реальном устройстве, как я это делал с андроид? Если да, то как?

Comment: без эппл компа не выйдет. либо покупать комп, либо дорогущий CI искать...

Comment: Без MacOS никак. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/mac/

Comment: Интересно, я наверно подзабыл что то - просто я был уверен что запускал на айфоне с видны, свое флатер приложение, пару лет назад..А вообще глянь сдесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220917/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-flutter-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ios

Comment: @Михаил Спасибо, бегу смотреть)

Comment: Можно попытаться хакинтош поставить. Но возни будет.....